# Is this the correct way to set an id for an element that doesn't have an id yet in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("a[href*='http://www.google.com']").attr('id','newId');
```

Can only reference it by `href`.

Comment: Better technique: If your code is generating the html in question, change your code to include the id attribute.

Comment: To make sure you only have one element with that ID, you could append the `:first` selector.

Comment: @pimvdb `.first()` would be better - `:first` is a jQuery extension which would prevent the browser's own native selector parser from being used.  See http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's the correct way to add an `id` attribute to an element that doesn't already have one.

However you should ensure that there's only one matching element, as it's incorrect to have two elements with the same ID on a page, e.g.:

```
$("a[href*='http://www.google.com']").first().attr('id', 'newId');
```

This would, of course, still leave you with the problem of what to do with the remaining matching elements, if any.  A possible solution would be:

```
$("a[href*='http://www.google.com']").attr('id', function(index, attr) {
    return 'newId_' + index;
});
```

which will assign the elements the IDs `newId_0`, `newId_1`, etc.